# ffmpeg on Windows Server Core 2022?

Tags: ffmpeg, windows-server

Recently upgraded to Windows Server Core 2022 and ffmpeg doesn't start.  No errors, no logs, no nothing. I thought I had seen mention of ffmpeg running on Server Core 2012 with the Essentials role installed, but no such role seems to exist for Core 2022.

What dependency would ffmpeg have that would cause a silent fail on this platform?

Comment: For checking the dependencies you may use [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) utility. I can't help you regarding Windows Server Core 2022, but I recommend you to post the exact version of FFmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

C:\windows\system32\AVICAP32.DLL and C:\windows\system32\MSVFW32.DLL can be copied from Windows Server 2022 LTSC (Desktop Edition) or Windows 10.

Copying those to the system32 folder, ffmpeg.exe should work again.